# NSoperation how to use it to wait for event?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I have application that connects to server (sends post request) via `NSURLConnection`, and receives some data from server. I want that to be happening in background on separate thread. I have seen `NSOperation` used for this purpose - as shown in this tutorial -

[Concurrent Operations Demystified](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)

But this is a little bit older tutorial (way back from 2009), and maybe some new ways are found to do this. Basically what i want to do is - start `NSOperation`, wait for it to receive data (because if I don't thread will end, and data will be lost) and then signal that data is ready (maybe via `NSNotificationCentre`)

The request i make is async, so i can use progress bar to wait for data. Is there something that i can call inside NSOperation block that causes thread to sleep until data is received? Like some loop that waits for certain condition to be met?

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is outdated, today you can code about the same thing much easier. Create an `NSOperationQueue` for your requests and use an `NSOperationBlock` in combination with a synchronous `NSURLConnection` to download the data:

```
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = /* build request */;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
        sendSynchronousRequest:request
        returningResponse:&response
        error:&error];
    /* handle errors and callbacks */
}];
```

The queue lets you set a limit on the number of concurrent requests and also supports cancellation for free (but not inside a request, of course).

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to use these new features?

Comment: Not sure, google for the keywords. These aren’t really new features, the code has been working since the release of iOS 5. And the sample code you’re looking at is about it, the rest you can easily figure out by trying and reading the reference docs.

Comment: Ok, but i'd like to use async request, since i am receiving a large file, I'd like to present to user progress bar on how much data is received... Something along lines of that tutorial. And when the whole file is downloaded i want to send that notification. There are four delegate methods on NSURLConnection that let me do that, i just have somehow watch that my thread is not finished until that happens, because i won't receive anything.

Comment: I don’t think you can create a determinate progress bar with the synchronous connection. The rest is easy, but if you really need the progress bar, you have to look into some other solution, like the [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/) suggested by Panagiotis.

Comment: @zoul How could I pass the `&error` given by NSURLConnection to a `completionBlock`? (Let's say I used `NSBlockOperation *blockOP = ...; [queue addOperation:blockOp];` instead of `addOperationWithBlock:`

Comment: What completion block? After the synchronous connection call returns you can call whatever you want, like pass the error to a custom block.

Answer (score 1):

If you take data from the web you might want to use [Asihttprequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which supports queues and synchronous/asynchronous data loading.

Comment: After @zoul reply, yes there is the NSOperationQueue -- but if you want simplicity use asi.

Comment: In my opinion the combination of `NSOperationQueue` with a synchronous `NSURLConnection` is so easy it beats depending on an external library.

Comment: Are we talking in ios 5? Because I need to keep a backwards compatibility with iphone 3 (for stupid "manager"/profit reasons) so I haven't used that eversince someone from so suggested me the Asi lib.

Comment: `NSBlockOperation` requires blocks, which means iOS 5, IIRC.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
     initWithTarget:self
     selector:@selector(Method)
     object:nil];
[self.Queue addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: -1, I don’t think this answers the question in any reasonably straightforward way.